# How to escape escape "=" or Equal to sign in batch script in a double quote string

Tags: batch-file, variables, echo

```
SET "gmail5=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/5/?tab=wm&ogbl#inbox"
echo %gmail5%
```

The output is

```
H:\local\CODE\Batch scripting\powershell\Config>.\test.bat   

H:\local\CODE\Batch scripting\powershell\Config>SET "gmail5=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/5/?tab=wm&ogbl#inbox"

H:\local\CODE\Batch scripting\powershell\Config>echo https://mail.google.com/mail/u/5/?tab=wm  & ogbl#inbox
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/5/?tab=wm
'ogbl#inbox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I checked the StackOverflow most of the post said that anything in "" is escaped along with =. I cannot figure out,why it gets recognized in echo. My use case is to use these strings in another batch script for vdesk.

```
vdesk create:4
vdesk on:1 run:%gmail5%
```

Comment: Nothing is escaped by quoting the string. But everything is safe within quotes. The `set` command is perfectly fine, but note that the quotes are not part of the string. When you `echo` the (unquoted) string, there is nothing safe. `Echo "%gmail5%"` would be fine (echo a quoted string, which makes `&` safe). Also `set gmail5` outputs the variable correctly (good for troubleshooting output). By using delayed expansion, also `echo !gmail5!` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Batch uses `&` to separate different commands on one line. It does not assume that `"..."` is a string - it *might* be, however unlikely, that the `"` is a legitimate character as a command parameter.

Hence, you need to escape the `&` with a caret (`^`) which should work with all "awkward" characters except `%` for which the escape is `%` itself.

Answer (score 0):

the thing you are trying to accomplish can be done in following way,your code was all right except every time when you print special characters use ^ or Cmd will confuse it for &(And) operater.

```
@echo off
SET "gmail5=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/5/?tab=wm^&ogbl#inbox"
echo %gmail5%
pause >nul
```